# Anaconda does not update to tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

no this has not already been answered somewhere else :).

When trying to upgrade tensorflow to version 2.1.0 in Anaconda on Window 10, I got either an error message (see below) or nothing but the version remains the same 1.13.1.

I've tried :

```
pip install tensorflow --upgrade (and different variation where I specify the version...)
pip install --user tensorflow
"same thing with pip3"
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
conda config --set ssl_verify False  (or no as I ve seen it some times)
conda remove certifi
conda install certifi
```

I've updated my pip to the latest version and tried again. I've also updated Anaconda to the latest version. I've tried updating via the Anaconda Navigator, everything goes smoothly..but the version remains the same. Even though when it's done scanning the packages required, it says version 2.1.0.

**Error Message :**
It starts downloading the package then suddenly during the download I get

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: SSL: DECRYPTION_FAIL_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2471).
```

I'ts a clean and fresh install of Anaconda, what's weird is that I have this version of Anaconda installed on a laptop and 2 desktop. (Python 3.7 / Spyder 4.0.1).
I never had the problem on my laptop (company laptop) but I have the problem with my personal desktop and company desktop.

I mention this because I've read post where people say Python 3.7 might be the cause. This is not my case I've been using tensorflow 2.1.0 on my laptop with Python 3.7 for a while without problem.

This has been driving me crazy for days thank you for your help

Thanks everybody,

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment? Are you using pip or conda to install tensorflow?

Comment: try   conda create -n tf tensorflow

Comment: @AMC I'm using conda to install usually, but I gave a try to pip as well in this case. What do you mean by content of the environment ? (I work in the '"base" environment, I never had to create new one so far).

Comment: @ Gerry P, It works but it's the equivalent of starting with a blank slate, so I have to reinstall all the libraries. It's a good workaround, but I'd like to understand what is blocking me in the original environment. Thank you

Comment: @YoanB. _(I work in the '"base" environment, I never had to create new one so far)._ You should always use other environments, so as to avoid breaking your Conda installation. That might be part of the issue here, you should consider reinstalling Conda, just to be sure.

Comment: @AMC, that's what i did first. Starting from a fresh new installation of Anaconda. But I still had the same problem. Creating a new environment works, but my goal being to reproduce some code on a different machine, I have to reinstall all libraries including pandas. It seems heavy, isn't there a easier solution to create a new env with a list of packages required ?

Comment: @YoanB. You can specify the dependencies in an environment.yml file and use that to create the env (see the [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file)).